# Why can't the @+id show when trying findViewById?

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdz05.png

I'm not sure why the 'totalPlus' id won't show up.

I've fixed the mismatch naming problem that the picture shows. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project or even restarting Eclipse itself?

Also, there may be some other problems/errors in your res folder that can affect the proper R.java auto-generation.

If those do not work, try to insert your textviews via the Graphical Layout and then rename them by right-clicking on them and select "Edit ID". This should do a proper re-factoring.

You can also take a look at the official Layout guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html/) .